# iOS - MPMoviePlayerController audio doubles when changing currentPlaybackRate

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using custom controls. When I change the playback rate like so:

```
[videoPlayer setCurrentPlaybackRate:2.0f];
```

The audio plays back at both1.0 and 2.0 (the audio doubles, like an echo). Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Any insight or direction would be greatly appreciated.